# Django single website structure

Tags: python, django, structure

I want to start a new django project. This will just be a relatively simple website to test django itself. So the way all tutorials structure their project is this:

- mysite

  - mysite
  - some_app
  - ...

For me it's not very clear what does what. I don't really need any app right now. Could I implement my website without using any app? Should I use an app? What would it be called for a simple website?

Comment: Projects vs. apps

What’s the difference between a project and an app? An app is a Web application that does something – e.g., a Weblog system, a database of public records or a simple poll app. A project is a collection of configuration and apps for a particular website. A project can contain multiple apps. An app can be in multiple projects. (From Django Documentation) If you want to reuse functions in other projects apps are the solution.

Comment: Well and for my specific case?
The project would be a website, the app as well?

Comment: As I understand Django, your website will start apps to get their functionallity.

Comment: And how would you name that app? I'm not quite sure who is responsible for what

Comment: Any name you want.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read Django doc already?
They have a [nice tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) on how to get started.

As for apps, in Django, you have a project containing one or more app. If you just want to try to build a simple website, your project called `mysite` will contain only one app.

Comment: how would you name that app?

Comment: As you wish, it is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need more than the main `mysite`, BUT, at the django documents, have a session that says:

> If your background is in plain old PHP (with no use of modern
>   frameworks), you’re probably used to putting code under the Web
>   server’s document root (in a place such as /var/www). With Django, you
>   don’t do that. It’s not a good idea to put any of this Python code
>   within your Web server’s document root, because it risks the
>   possibility that people may be able to view your code over the Web.
>   That’s not good for security.
>
> Put your code in some directory outside of the document root, such as
>   /home/mycode.

This model may have been designed with focus on safety. 
Some files in `mysite` could be used to control things in another `apps`, so i think that is a 'best pratice' to follow this model.

[Font](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/)

Answer (score 0):

if u aren't in need of an app you can avoid creating one. just give your `view` in `views.py` of your project set the url and u r all set to go.
here the first `mysite` folder is just an usual folder u can change the name in ur convenience next `mysite` is your project folder and recommended not to change it and next `some_app` is the application name(you can name your app anything relevant but in proper convention.)

and follow django documentation and djangogirls tutorial for better understanding.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/

https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/